# how to find all files under directory different directories

Tags: linux, command-line, find

How can you find files name 'xyz' under directories name 'abc'?

something like this....but its not working.

```
find . -type d -name 'abc' -exec find {} -type f -name 'xyz' \;

find . -not -path 'abc' -prune -o -type f -name 'xyz'
```

I can't just find files based on their name alone, b/c multiple directories NOT named 'abc' will have a file w/ the name 'xyz'

Comment: think I actually got it.  find . -type f -name "xyz" -path "*abc*"

Answer (score 0):

I think you could do

```
root@localhost:~# find /home/ -type f -name 'authorized_keys' -path '*/.ssh/*'
```

where

- `.ssh` is your directory `abc`
- `authorized_keys` is your file name `xyz`
- `/home/` is your starting directory `.`